# Is there a way to import from this node module with 'import' instead of 'require'?

Tags: node.js, npm, import, export, require

I'm using this node module 'deep-equal' () and so far the only way I've been able to access the function in it is with `var equal = require('deep-equal');`, as suggested in the documentation. I usually use `import` instead of `require`, and am wondering if it's possible to use `import` with this module. The main function is exported from the file in this line:

```
var deepEqual = module.exports = function (actual, expected, opts) {...}
```

Is it possible to import this function with `import`, or is it only possible with `require`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you actually can.

If you're using `nodejs LTS` then you'll have to use `.mjs` extension for the file where you're using `import` and pass `experimental-modules` flag while running `node` process.

```
// foo.mjs
import equal from 'deep-equal';

node --experimental-modules foo.mjs
```

As of `nodejs 12.3.0` you can simply pass the `experimental-modules`. From [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#)

> Once enabled, Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to node as the initial input, or when referenced by import statements within ES module code

Also you can specify `type` as `module` in your `package.json`:

```
// package.json
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

From docs

> Files ending with .js or .mjs, or lacking any extension, will be loaded as ES modules when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module"

Comment: Hi @1556089774, thanks for the info. Why can't you import it the regular way with " import equal from 'deep-equal' " without the other stuff?

Comment: The feature has `experimental` flag. So in short, not supported as *stable*

Comment: Sorry what I mean is, what is it about the way the module is written, with "var deepEqual = module.exports = function (actual, expected, opts) {...}", that makes it so that you can't import with " import equal from 'deep-equal' ", the way you could if the module were written like "export default deep-equal {...}"

Comment: tested on my machine, and import with the experimental flag works fine. var deepEqual = module.exports = this is only asigning module.exports object to deepEqual, now they refer the same object, that's all

Comment: Re "this is only assigning module.exports object to deepEqual" etc: why does this make it such that you can import with "var deep = require('deep-equal')" but not with "import {deep} from 'deep-equal'"?

Comment: `but not with "import {deep} from 'deep-equal'"`, now you're confusing `default` export vs `named` export, `import { something } ...` is importing a named export, if exports object does not contain `something` as named export, you cannot actually import it (something would be `undefined`). equivalent of `var deep = require('deep-equal')` using import syntax is `import deep from 'deep-equal'`

Comment: Right, but here I can't use `import deep from 'deep-equal'` either. The module doesn't have a default export. I'm still wondering what it is about `var deepEqual = module.exports = function (actual, expected, opts) {...}` that allows me to import a function from it with `require`, but prevents me from importing it with `import` unless I use something like foo.mjs.

Comment: This `var deepEqual = module.exports = function (actual, expected, opts) {...}` is the default export. Also I tested on my machine and it works. `import deep from 'deep-equal'` gives me the exported function

Comment: Interestingly, 'import deep ...' is working in my React Native app but throwing an error when I try to do it in a .js file that I run with node. The error is "(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import deep from 'deep-equal'
                                                                     ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" .   Any idea why that would be?

Comment: In react native you're able to import due to babel plugin. The error is because you're either not passing `--experimental-modules` (prior to node 12 you'll also have to name the files with extension `.mjs`) or using an old version of node which does not support module event with experimental-modules